# Encrypt audio mp3 file while downloading and decrypt it while playing in android

Tags: java, audio, encryption, download, mp3

I have an android application which downloads and play mp3 files. But I want to encrypt audio files while downloading and then decrypt to play it. I have already checked everywhere in the internet but did not find any solution. Could anyone please help me how to encrypt audio files while downloading and then decrypt during playing
Here is my code to download the files

```
     private void download() {
    if (Constant.arrayList_play.size() > 0) {

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Myapp/cache");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(root, Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getMp3Name() + ".mp3");

        if (!file.exists()) {

            String url = Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getMp3Url();
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.downloading) + " - " + Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getMp3Name());
            request.setTitle(Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getMp3Name());
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Myapp/cache/" + Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getMp3Name() + ".mp3"));
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);

            new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                    String json = JsonUtils.getJSONString(Constant.URL_DOWNLOAD_COUNT + Constant.arrayList_play.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getId());
                    Log.e("aaa - ", json);
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.downloading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.already_download), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_song_selected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

So could you please help me with a code.

Comment: Please try to ask a real question related to the problem you are having. As it is, we have to guess your problem based on your statements of fact.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed a point while asking the question which I have edited now. Actually I want help in how to encrypt audio files while downloading and decrypt it during playing. I have tried a lot to achieve it but did not succeeded.

Comment: What's the reason for this?  If you're trying to protect media files, know that the client that has the decryption key can always decrypt it so there's little point.

Comment: Yes, I know if anyone has decryption key they can decrypt it but I want to decrypt for the rest who are unauthorised. Could you please help with a code

Comment: We still don't understand where is the problem. Just keeping it simple - you can use https for encryption in transit and give access to media only to authorized users. Or do you want to download the content encrypted? Then you cannot use the default player

Comment: I am using exoplayer for playing songs. My problem is that without encryption the songs can be easily downloaded and anyone can re-upload it anywhere. So it leads to illegal uploading , so to prevent piracy we need to encrypt the songs while download. But I am unable to perform the encryption despite lot of try. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: yes I want to download the encrypted and then again decrypt it when required to play

Comment: Have you found a solution? I totally get your point. It seems, we need to use jetpack. But as of now, I have no idea how or what exactly

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have not found any solution. For the timing I am looking at different aspects of my project leaving it for other time. If you find anything tell me we could discuss about it.

Comment: @dp2050 I just got a solution which I seem is working fine

Comment: Hey @MrinmoyMk can you share your solution, please? I also have the same problem

Comment: @coolbeatz71 are you using exoplayer to play the audio files?

Comment: Yes, @MrinmoyMk  I am using exoplayer. But I want to decrypt the file as it's playing. Means, to decrypt byte by byte and play the decrypted stream without storing the decrypted file. This will avoid illegal copy

Comment: @MrinmoyMk, you mentioned that you have found the solution. Can you share it here? Or the link(s) to helpful content?

Comment: Okay I have added the solution. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question and have been using it in my app since many days without any problem so I think it is good to answer my own question also as many users had asked for solution in comments. So just follow the below codes-

```
  //Downloading and encrypting the audio

  AesCipherDataSink encryptingDataSink = new AesCipherDataSink(
      Util.getUtf8Bytes("4J95qN8RxBP8hTpk"),
      new DataSink() {
       private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

       @Override
       public void open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
               fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }

       @Override
       public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
          fileOutputStream.write(buffer, offset, length);
        }

       @Override
       public void close() throws IOException {
             fileOutputStream.close();
         }
        });

   // Push the data through the sink, and close everything.
   encryptingDataSink.open(new DataSpec(Uri.fromFile(file)));
   URL downloadURL = new URL(strings[0]);
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
   connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.connect();
   if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      return "Server error";
   }

   InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int newLength;
   while ((newLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        encryptingDataSink.write(buffer, 0, newLength);
    }
   encryptingDataSink.close();
   inputStream.close();



   //decrypting and playing the audio
   DataSource.Factory factory =
                new CustomDataSourceFactory(
                        context,
                        new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(new OkHttpClient(), Util.getUserAgent(context,
                              context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
                );

    MediaSource videoSource =
                new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory)
                        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(tempFile.getAbsolutePath()));
    exoPlayer.addMediaSource(videoSource);

    
   //CustomDataSourceFactoryClass

    public class CustomDataSourceFactory implements DataSource.Factory {

      private final Context context;
      private final DataSource.Factory baseDataSourceFactory;


      public CustomDataSourceFactory(Context context, DataSource.Factory baseDataSourceFactory) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.baseDataSourceFactory = baseDataSourceFactory;
       }

       @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
         return new CryptedDefaultDataSource(context, baseDataSourceFactory.createDataSource());
         }
      }

   //CryptedDafaultDataSource
    public class CryptedDefaultDataSource implements DataSource {

      private final List<TransferListener> transferListeners;
      private final DataSource baseDataSource;
      private @Nullable
      DataSource fileDataSource,aesCipherDataSource,dataSource;
      private Context context;

      CryptedDefaultDataSource(Context context, DataSource baseDataSource) {
         this.context=context;
         this.baseDataSource = Assertions.checkNotNull(baseDataSource);
         transferListeners = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      @Override
      public void addTransferListener(TransferListener transferListener) {
       baseDataSource.addTransferListener(transferListener);
       transferListeners.add(transferListener);
       maybeAddListenerToDataSource(fileDataSource, transferListener);
       maybeAddListenerToDataSource(aesCipherDataSource, transferListener);
      }

     @Override
     public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
        Assertions.checkState(dataSource == null);
        if (Util.isLocalFileUri(dataSpec.uri)) {
          dataSource = getCryptedDataSource(getFileDataSource());
        } else {
          dataSource = getCryptedDataSource(baseDataSource);
        }
       return dataSource.open(dataSpec);
      }

     @Override
      public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws IOException {
         return Assertions.checkNotNull(dataSource).read(buffer, offset, readLength);
       }

      @Nullable
      @Override
       public Uri getUri() {
        return dataSource == null ? null : dataSource.getUri();
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, List<String>> getResponseHeaders() {
          return dataSource == null
            ? DataSource.super.getResponseHeaders()
            : dataSource.getResponseHeaders();
       }

     @Override
     public void close() throws IOException {
       if (dataSource != null) {
        try {
            dataSource.close();
        } finally {
            dataSource = null;
        }
      }
     }

    private DataSource getFileDataSource() {
      if (fileDataSource == null) {
         fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
         addListenersToDataSource(fileDataSource);
       }
       return fileDataSource;
     }

    private DataSource getCryptedDataSource(DataSource upstreamDataSource) {
      if (aesCipherDataSource == null) {
        aesCipherDataSource = new AesCipherDataSource("4J95qN8RxBP8hTpk".getBytes(),upstreamDataSource);
        addListenersToDataSource(aesCipherDataSource);
      }
      return aesCipherDataSource;
     }

   private void addListenersToDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
     for (int i = 0; i < transferListeners.size(); i++) {
        dataSource.addTransferListener(transferListeners.get(i));
     }
   }

     private void maybeAddListenerToDataSource(
        @Nullable DataSource dataSource, TransferListener listener) {
      if (dataSource != null) {
        dataSource.addTransferListener(listener);
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Can it support seek and buffering?

Comment: Yes it support seeking